# Histogram is automatically created instead of a barchart

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to create a barchart (not a histogram) of a discrete variable that takes values {1,2,3,4}.

```
import pandas as pd
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv', parse_dates=[0])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
counts = collections.Counter(train['season'].values)
vals = np.arange(len(counts))
axes[0].bar(counts, vals, color='red')
axes[0].set(title='Season')

plt.show()
```

However I get a plot similar to a histogram ("bins" instead of values on X axis - 1,2,3 and 4).
[image]

```
print train['season'].values
[1 1 1 ..., 4 4 4]

print counts
Counter({4: 2734, 2: 2733, 3: 2733, 1: 2686})

print vals
[0 1 2 3]
```

Comment: can you post a sample of `train['season'].values`?

Comment: @tom: please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of things to fix

1. I think you have the vals and counts the wrong way round
2. you don't need to create vals for the values on the x axis, you can use
   `counts.keys()`
3. to access the counts, you need to use
   `counts.values()`
4. to set the x ticks properly, you can set them
   to `counts.keys()` as well
5. you also need to align the bars to the
   center, rather than left edge (which is the default behaviour)

Putting that all together, please try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv', parse_dates=[0])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
counts = collections.Counter(train['season'].values)
axes[0].bar(counts.keys(), counts.values(), color='red',align='center')
axes[0].set(title='Season')

axes[0].set_xticks(counts.keys())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'season' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4., 1., 3.])})
df.season.value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]